# CSS transition with nowrap is not smooth

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to allow CSS transition of a sidebar, best described as this image:
[image]

While in a single line `{white-space: nowrap}` works grandly, I am having trouble ensuring a smooth sidebar-collapsed animation as lines seem to break down. Giving `nowrap` on the expanded sidebar just breaks it.

Here's a jsfiddle for further demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/elvista/4K4fh/

Some guidance will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a child element to the sidebar which remains the original width and set the sidebar to `overflow: hidden`, you should get the result you want. See: http://jsfiddle.net/49nf8/

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I wanted. I had tried `overflow:hidden` before, but not with an extra element. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When you make the sidebar collapsed to `width 50px` the words like "consectetur" doesn't have space to occupy within the 50px `width`. You can try using [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) to break the words and occupy the 50px width on collapse.

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/7LJQp/)

```
.sidebar-collapsed {
    width: 50px;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;
     // Non standard for webkit
     word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I had a different goal in mind. woahdave provided it :)